# Get Session Data by Id

Tags: php, jquery, session

How can I get the session data in PHP? I want to get the `addid` value in PHP but I am not able to do this. Why? Below is my chrome session data

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['addid'];
```

Chrome Session Data:

[image]

Comment: sessionStorage (ie. what you're seeing in the browser console) and the session on the server side (what you're accessing in your PHP code) are two separate entities. They are not at all the same thing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i know that but how do i get it in php.

Comment: Submit the values in a form, or send an AJAX request

Comment: i am using session js library to create session i can easily get it by js but i want to get it on some other page where i can't use js. want to get it by php

Comment: And I just told you how to do that...

Comment: actually i am getting payment response form third party and i have to update my database using  __addid_.

Comment: Still doesn't change the method you need to use to send data from JS to PHP.

Comment: but here i can not send data and retrive. here i am getting response from some other third party .

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if there is any way to get this data using PHP please tell me how to get!

Comment: No. You need to send it to the server. As I said before, and now for the last time, you need to send the data in a form submission, or through an AJAX request. If you're already getting data from a third party it's likely you're already making one AJAX request so another shouldn't be too taxing for you