# not able to JSON encode an array

Tags: php, json, jsonencoder

when trying to json_encode() an array, array not encoding 
my array is :

```
$jsonData = array(
        'addressId' => $addid,
        'paymentMethod' => 2,
        'transactionId' => $orderid
);
print_r($jsonData);
```

it prints :

```
Array ( [addressId] => 28 [paymentMethod] => 2 [transactionId] => ORDS63375431 )
```

and json encoding:

```
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
echo $jsonDataEncoded;
```

it prints :

```
 {"addressId":"
```

what i am doing wrong?

here is my full code:

```
$addid = '<script>document.write($.session.get("addid"));</script>';
    $orderid = $_POST["ORDERID"];
    $accessToken = $_COOKIE['accessToken'];
    $url = 'http://bookwise.co.in/app/api/carts/checkout';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $jsonData = array(
        'addressId' => $addid,
        'paymentMethod' => 2,
        'transactionId' => $orderid
    );
    print_r($jsonData);
    $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
    echo $jsonDataEncoded;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','X-API-KEY: '.$accessToken.'')); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Just tested it online and it works just fine, here's what I'm getting : `string(65) "{"addressId":28,"paymentMethod":2,"transactionId":"ORDS63375431"}"`

Comment: `var_dump($jsonData)` please.  let's see if you have any invisible characters in there.  If not, then we are going to have to close this one as `Off-topic: Cannot Reproduce`

Comment: @teeyo i am editing my full code just check

Comment: @teeyo when i tried  json_encode($jsonData, true) getting response but it give me script value which {"addressId":"\u003Cscript\u003Edocument.write($.session.get(\"addid\"));\u003C\/script\u003E","paymentMethod":2,"transactionId":"ORDS63375431"}{"status":false,"message":"Invalid Address"}

Comment: I tried your code online, it seems to properly encode your array to JSON. See - http://codepad.org/8AT2hS4Z

Comment: You have invisible script tags in your `$addid` value.

Comment: like I said before, your code is fine :) ... I did the same as @gauravparmar and it worked perfectly, try it yourself : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec7cba9e491f2a058fc3e2003e6a00038936d81f

Comment: The content for `json_encode` must be utf8 encoded.

Comment: @teeyo but why it showing me script value in json and it showing fine in array

Comment: have you tried: `$addid=$_SESSION['addid'];`?  (and don't forget `session_start()` at the top of your script)  If this fixes it, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa i can not use this you can see my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863960/get-session-data-by-id

Comment: Then I guess you are going to need to do a SJAX request like Rory said

Comment: The more I read about this matter, the more it seems you have made a rod for your own back.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45212059/2943403

Comment: What are you willing to do to remedy your situation?  Are you going to copy your js session storage to server-side session storage so that you can access it?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes exactly.

Comment: If you are going to port your js session data to server side storage, then you will have an easy time repairing your snippet. Please remove this question and post a question if you have issues after you have reconfigured things.